# Getting table name within mstest unit test with data from Microsoft Test Manager

Tags: c#, unit-testing, datasource, testcase, microsoft-test-manager

I have test methods decorated with a `DataSource` attribute like:

```
[DataSource(PROVIDER_INVARIANT_NAME, CONNECTION_STRING, 
"Test Case#", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), 
TestMethod]
```

with the test case number in MTM replacing "Test Case#". I'm trying to get that number within the unit test but `TestContext.DataRow.Table.TableName` is always "Table1". Can anyone tell me how to get the real value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm wrong, the "TestCase#"  cannot  be replaced by MTM, so propably you have manually added it in all your `DataSource` attributes.

This value is `constant`. Why don't you add a constant variable to your `TestClass` and then use it on both the `DataSourceAttribute` and your `TestMethod`?

**EDIT**
You can also access the `DataSourceAttribute` directly:

```
[TestClass]
public class TestClass
{
    public DataSourceAttribute DataSource
    {
        get
        {
            return (DataSourceAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(TestClass).
                GetMethod("TestMethod"), typeof(DataSourceAttribute));
        }
    }

    [DataSource(PROVIDER_INVARIANT_NAME, CONNECTION_STRING, 
        "Test Case#", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        string TestCaseId = DataSource.TableName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I've manually added it. I am having to do it that way at the moment, but I'd much prefer to declare it once in the datasource and then have it accessible in the TestContext. Am I right in thinking that TestContext.DataRow.Table.TableName should be populated?

Comment: Yes, I also tried it and the `TableName` was always "Table1". Check my edited answer if this will help you. However, I still believe that it's more easy if you use a constant variable.